# Multiple deploy via Maven to Android devices on a USB Hub

Tags: android, maven, ddms

I've searched on SO for a while on this but cannot find a definitive answer.

I've recently purchased a 7 port USB Hub for my dev machine, with 7 differing Android devices on it.

This was done primarily to keep everything all charged, but I am also trying to find out if it possible to configure Maven or even DDMS) to recognize the devices and deploy to all of them at once through the hub?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current version of Android SDK does not support install apk on multiple connected devices at once. This is the hard limitation, so the only workaround at the moment is to iterate the attached devices and issue the install command for each of them.

If you look at the [android-maven-plugin documentation](http://maven-android-plugin-m2site.googlecode.com/svn/deploy-mojo.html#device), you can see there is an interesting parameter in android:deploy goal that you can specify in pom.xml:

> **device:**
>
> Specifies which device to connect to, by serial number. Special values "usb" and "emulator" are also valid, for selecting the only USB connected device or the only running emulator, respectively.
>
> - Type: java.lang.String
> - Required: No
> - Expression: ${android.device}

Well, the documentation claims that it will install apk to the only connected device. I have tested it myself, it also work if multiple devices are connected.

Sample pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
  <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <extensions>true</extensions>
  <configuration>
    <sdk>
      <platform>13</platform>
    </sdk>
    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
    <!-- Install apk to multiple attached devices -->
    <device>usb</device>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Sample log by running `mvn android:deploy`:

```
[INFO] Waiting for initial device list from the Android Debug Bridge
[INFO] Found 2 devices connected with the Android Debug Bridge
[INFO] android.device parameter set to usb
[INFO] Device 0123456789abcd_samsung_GT-I9100 found.
[INFO] Successfully uninstalled com.company.app from 0123456789abcd_samsung_GT-I9100
[INFO] Device 0123456789efg_HTC_HTCDesire found.
[INFO] Successfully uninstalled com.company.app from 0123456789efg_HTC_HTCDesire
[INFO] Found 2 devices connected with the Android Debug Bridge
[INFO] android.device parameter set to usb
[INFO] Device 0123456789abcd_samsung_GT-I9100 found.
[INFO] Successfully installed C:\workspace\my-app\target\app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.apk to 0123456789abcd_samsung_GT-I9100
[INFO] Device 0123456789efg_HTC_HTCDesire found.
[INFO] Successfully installed C:\workspace\my-app\target\app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.apk to 0123456789efg_HTC_HTCDesire
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If you want to know how android-maven-plugin implement it, check out [source code here](https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jayway/maven/plugins/android/AbstractAndroidMojo.java#L649).

Comment: Hmm, I already have an almost identical Maven setup, but calling building and deploying from Maven still doesn't recognize the devices on the hub. I think I have a hardware issue, so I will accept this.

Comment: @MoKargas, you could use command `adb devices` to check if all devices connected via usb hub are detected and attached.

Comment: Thanks guys, re-installing the Android Maven Plugin combined with Manfred's information below, fixed my personal configuration issue. Yorkw's answer is spot on.

Comment: Btw. I have updated the help text for the device parameter to be a bit clearer I hope. Should be out with the next release.

Answer (score 1):

As yorkow correctly mentions the Android Maven Plugin supports multiple connected devices and emulators.

In fact it does so either for all attached devices and emulators (no parameter), all attached devices (device parameter set to usb), all emulators (device parameter set to emulator) or a specific devices (device parameter set to serial number of the device).

In order to use the plugin I would suggest to look at the [Android Maven Plugin website](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/) as well as the [chapter about Android development with it in the book Maven: The Complete Reference](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/android-dev.html)

The main thing to keep in mind is that this parameter and [the multi device support applies for all device interaction goals](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/android-dev-sect-device.html) (deploy, undeploy, redeploy, run, instrument, pull and push) so you can e.g. run all tests on a number of devices or push files to all attached devices as well.

Also depending on the operating system you will need to add the USB manufacturer identification to the udev rules or other setup. See more on [the dev site](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html).

Try

```
adb devices
```

first and then use the Android Maven Plugin goal to see what it can detect with

```
mvn android:devices
```

PS: I am core committer on the plugin and author of the linked book content..

Comment: Thanks Manfred. Re-installing the Android Maven Plugin (combined with checking via mvn android:devices) fixed all issues and mass deployment now works excellently!

Comment: What do you mean by reinstalling?

Comment: There is no install process necessary though.. so I was wondering. If you got it in your POM Maven will do the rest..

Comment: Perhaps install is the wrong word to use - I did use the POM, but I had to delete .m2\repository\com\jayway\maven\plugins\android\generation2 to get it to work again. When I rebuilt and re-deployed my project, it downloaded and worked fine.